# экспоненциальное скользящее среднее с учётом различных по длине временных интервалов

Tags: математика, время, временные-ряды, вычислительный-эксперимент

я хочу рассчитать экспоненциальное скользящее среднее по следующей формуле

EMA<sub>t</sub> = val<sub>t</sub> * α + EMA<sub>t - 1</sub> * (1 - α)

но у меня нет всех данных, у меня есть только некоторые данные с большим разрывом во времени.

например timestamps=[43439, 43628, 43753, 43974, 44136] для data=[5, 4, 4, 5, 5]

я использовал стандартное значение для сглаживания - α = 2 / (n + 1)

но из-за неравных интервалов мне кажется, что это неправильно.

я читал про обработку неполных временных рядов - заполнение средним, интерполяция и так далее, но не знаю, стоит ли ими пользоваться - интервалы времени действительно очень большие, и *данные зависят не только от времени.*

я видел [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023860/exponential-moving-average-sampled-at-varying-times) вопрос, но я не понимаю, как получить α аналогичным образом для моего случая

Comment: http://www.eckner.com/research.html  Первая ссылка и код на С,R похожи на то, что вам нужно